# Where is Xcode 3.0's output window?

Tags: xcode

I'm learning Xcode off a slightly older (10.2) book that deals with Project Builder. I've been using Xcode for ansi C for a while, but I can't find the output window that appears when you Build & Run an app. I am launching my apps from the commandline, but of course that doesn't help me if I want to set breakpoints or something. Where is the program output window that should appear when I build & run. Do I have it hidden or something ? Why can't I find it ?

Answer (score 6):

Shift-Cmd-R brings up the output window.

Comment: There's also a preference in XCode to bring up the console after each launch - Xcode->Preferences->Debugging->On Start Show Console.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few windows that you should know about:

- Debugger Console (keyboard shortcut = Shift-Cmd-R): This will show you any console output and you can click the breakpoints button to break into the GDB console debugger
- Debugger (keyboard shortcut = Shift-Cmd-Y): This is the debugger window that shows your breakpoints with the source and includes table views for local variables and the stack
- Breakpoints window (keyboard shortcut = Option-Cmd-B): This is a nifty window to find and manage breakpoints in a project

This [cocoaheads talk](http://theocacao.com/document.page/570) has a lot of useful info about debugging with xcode.

Hope this helps.